# C# group by a column and form hierarchical data with other columns

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to group a column and form the the rest of the columns as child, hierarchical data:

[image]

I am trying to group by Code and form the parent and child relationship from a flat list, below is the hierarchical data I am trying to form:

source list:

```
 public class ItemAssignmentFlatList
 {
  public int Code { get; set; }
  public string Type { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public int ItemCode{ get; set; }
  public DateTime EffectiveDate{ get; set; }
  public string Area{ get; set; }
  public string TaxCode{ get; set; }
  public string LocationId { get; set; }
 }
```

Need to convert above flat list into below List of hierarchical data:

```
public class ItemInfo
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<TaxInfo> TaxPlan { get; set; }
}

public class TaxPlan 
{
    public int ItemCode{ get; set; }
    public DateTime EffectiveDate{ get; set; }
    public string Area{ get; set; }
    public string TaxCode{ get; set; }
    public string LocationId { get; set; }
}
```

Need hierarchical list with above flat data list with C# extension methods.

I have below code, but looking for clean code to reduce number of lines:

```
var items= results.GroupBy(x => new { x.Code, x.Type });

List<ItemInfo> result = new List<ItemInfo>();

foreach (var group in items)
{
  var taxPlans = group.
                   Select(y => new TaxPlan
                   {
                     TaxArea = y.TaxArea,
                     ItemCode = y.ItemCode
                   });

  var itemInfo= new ItemInfo
                     {
                       Code = group.FirstOrDefault().Code,
                       Type = group.FirstOrDefault().Type,
                       Description = group.FirstOrDefault().Description,
                       TaxPlan = taxPlans.ToList()
                     };

   result.Add(itemInfo);
}
```

Comment: What is the source data coming from?  Like an array of an array of strings?

Comment: You need help deserializing the json and then forming the table? You need help with linq?

Comment: I edited question, I don't need JSON I gave it for example on how the hierarchical data looks, i need a flat list to be converted into hierarchical data of ItemInfo & TaxPlan child list, source is ItemAssignmentFlatList collection with flat data

Comment: "Any help" is too broad. Where did you experience problems doing this? It looks like one `GroupBy` would suffice.

Comment: @GertArnold sir I am looking a way to write lesser number of lines of code, I posted my answer below, looking for clean code which can be done by group by and form result without any foreach loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you have a sequence of similar object, and you want to make "Items with their SubItems", based on common properties in your source sequence, consider to use [one of the overloads of Enumerable.GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____2__)

Because you don't just want "Groups of source items" but you want to specify your output, consider to use the overload that has a parameter resultSelector.

- parameter keySelector: what should all elements in a group have in common
- parameter resultSelector: use the common thing, and all elements that have this common thing to make one output element.

.

```
IEnumerable<ItemAssignmentFlatList> flatItemAssignments = ...
IEnumerable<ItemInfo> items = flatItemAssignments

    // make groups with same {Code, Type, Description}
    .GroupBy(flatItemAssignment => new {Code, Type, Description},

    // parameter resultSelector: take the common CodeTypeDescription,
    // and all flatItemAssignments that have this common value
    // to make one new ItemInfo
    (codeTypeDescription, flatItemAssignmentsWithThisCodeTypeDescription) => new ItemInfo
    {
        Code = codeTypeDescription.Code,
        Type = codeTypeDescription.Type,
        Description = codeTypeDescription.Description,

        TaxPlans = flatItemAssignmentsWithThisCodeTypeDescription
            .Select(flatItemAssignment => new TaxPlan
            {
                ItemCode = flatItemAssignment.ItemCode,
                EffectiveDate = flatItemAssignment.EffectiveDate,
                Area = flatItemAssignment.Area,
                ...
            })
            .ToList(),
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?:

```
var input = new List<ItemAssignmentFlatList>(){
    new ItemAssignmentFlatList{
        Code = 1,
        Area = "a"
    },
    new ItemAssignmentFlatList{
        Code = 1,
        Area = "b"
    },
    new ItemAssignmentFlatList{
        Code = 2,
        Area = "c"
    }
};

input
    .GroupBy(
        x => x.Code,
        (int code, IEnumerable<ItemAssignmentFlatList> items) =>
        {
            var first = items.FirstOrDefault();
            
            var key = new ItemInfo
            {
                Code = first.Code
                //, ...
            };

            var plan = items.
                Select(y => new TaxPlan
                {
                    Area = y.Area
                    //, ...
                });

            return new
            {
                key = key,
                items = plan
            };
        }
    ).Dump();
```